# Hide "New Page" and "Edit Page" option from Site Actions menu of Publishing site

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

How do we hide the "Edit Page" option from Site Actions menu of a publishing site.  I am able to hide "New Page" option using following xml:-

```
<HideCustomAction Id="HideCreatePublishingPage" GroupId="SiteActions" HideActionId="PublishingSiteActionsMenuCustomizer" Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"> </HideCustomAction>
```

However,  till now I am not able to find any option for hiding "Edit Page".

Please suggest...

Answer (score 3):

You can [try](http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/07/15/how-to-hide-publishing-site-actions-menu-links/comment-page-1/#comment-8147):

```
<HideCustomAction 
    Id="HideEditPage"
    GroupId="SiteActions"
    HideActionId="MenuItem_EditPage"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu" />
```

But it didn't work for me.

The Edit Page button is actually hardcoded into the master page. If you have a custom master page (or can create a custom master page), you can hide/comment out/delete the following control:

```
<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_EditPage"
    Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editpage%>"
    Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editpagedescriptionv4%>"
    ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/ActionsEditPage.png"
    MenuGroupId="100"
    Sequence="110"
    ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="javascript:ChangeLayoutMode(false);"
    />
```